# Epoxy requires every model attribute to implement equals and hashCode error

Tags: android, epoxy

I have created a small test app for this issue here:  (https://github.com/Winghin2517/EpoxyExample2).

I would like to pass a list of objects into the epoxy controller so that I can generate a graph. I have however encountered this error when building the app:

> error: Epoxy Processor Exception: Type in Iterable does not implement
>   hashCode. Type: kwaai.com.exampleepoxy_hashcodeequals.GraphData (View
>   Prop {view='HeaderView', name='setLineChart',
>   type=java.util.LinkedList})
>   Epoxy requires every model attribute to implement equals and hashCode
>   so that changes in the model can be tracked. If you want the attribute
>   to be excluded, use the option 'DoNotHash'. If you want to ignore this
>   warning use the option 'IgnoreRequireHashCode'

I think it is because I using the @ModelProp on a List of Objects (LinkedList of GraphDataFeed) and not on a primitive type as per the example app from Epoxy.

```
@ModelProp
public void setLineChart(LinkedList<GraphData> graphDataFeed) { }
```

So I folllowed the options and modified my @ModelProp to reflect this:

```
@ModelProp(options = ModelProp.Option.IgnoreRequireHashCode)
```

After the change the app builds and runs correctly. You can see the graph below.

[image]

However, I do not want to ignore the attribute as I understand Epoxy uses Diffing to update the models in the recyclerview: https://github.com/airbnb/epoxy/wiki/Diffing

Ignoring the attribute might mean that my models do not get updated correctly in the recyclerview.
In the guidance material here (https://github.com/airbnb/epoxy/wiki/Epoxy-Models#annotations), I see it says:

> A model's state is determined by its equals and hashCode
>   implementations, which is based on the value of all of the model's
>   properties.
>
> This state is used in diffing to determine when a model has changed so
>   Epoxy can update the view.
>
> These methods are generated so you don't have to created them
>   manually.

Why are these methods not generated for me then and if they are not generated, how do I generate these methods myself to get rid of the error?

Answer (score -2):

Your `GraphData` class needs to implement equals and hashcode. It says this right in the error message you copied

`Type in Iterable does not implement hashCode. Type: kwaai.com.exampleepoxy_hashcodeequals.GraphData`